# How to return 401 HTTP status when client omits any of enabled authentication schemes in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

We use 2 authentication schemes (Bearer, MTLS) in ASP.NET Core application.

When client ignores to send Client Certificate AND Bearer token, the response is 401 which is expect.

When client sends just Client Certificate OR just Bearer token, the authentication passes and request fails farther on authorization with 403 status code.

Is there a way how to make all authentication methods mandatory and return 401 status code when Client Certificate OR Bearer token is missing?

```
// Authentication and Authorization setup:
IServiceCollection services = . . .
            . . .
services.AddAuthentication(MtlsAuthenticationHandler.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMtlsAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        . . .
    });
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireMtlsAndBearer", 
        builder => builder.AddAuthenticationSchemes(MtlsAuthenticationHandler.AuthenticationScheme, JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddRequirements(. . .)
            .AddRequirements(. . .));
});


// Controller:
[HttpGet("v1/endpoint")]
[Authorize("RequireMtlsAndBearer")]  
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
. . .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion. You can do this
in Configure method of startup class

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?status={0}");
```

and then in HomeContoller:

```
   [HttpGet("/Error"), HttpPost("/Error")]
    public IActionResult Error([FromQuery] int status)
    {
        string errors1 = "some info";

        if (status == 403)
        {
            return new JsonResult(new { message = "your description", 
            statusCode=401,errors=errors1 });
       }
       else
        {
            return new JsonResult(new { message = "UNDEFINED_ERROR", statusCode = 
            status, errors = errors1 });
        }
   }
```

Comment: While the above code could work, it's not recommended to do so. 401 code is unauthorized, while 403 is forbidden. Both codes are similar, but aren't the same. If you replace all 403 codes for 401 codes, on the long run, this would lead to other developers consuming your services to not known what is really happening. This link maybe helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @Enrique González your comment is absolutely true,but on question it seems like these conditions is ok.

Comment: We don't want to replace all 403 with 401. We just want to adjust behavior. In our opinion authentication should not pass when either of two authentication schemes is missing in the request.

Comment: so use of a filtercontext or custom policy : public class AuthorizeHandle: AuthorizationHandler<AuthorizeRequirment>{HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,SoftExpirationPolicyRequirment requirement){var authorizationFilterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;if (yourchecks)
                {
                    authorizationFilterContext.Result = new JsonResult("message") { StatusCode = 401 };
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }}}